# JavaScript препроцессор (объединение, сжатие)

Tags: javascript, сжатие, объединение, препроцессор

Здравствуйте. Есть задача, на сайте подключено много скриптов (всяких кусков голого[ужас просто], целых либ, отдельных объектов). Нужно это все дело оптимизировать.

1. Необходимо все скрипты объединить в один большой скрипт
2. При этом нужно юзать какой-либо препроцессор (выбор падает на TypeScript)
3. При компилирования препроцессором выходной файл должен минифицироваться
4. В итоге, полученный большой файл, нужно использовать не целиком всегда, а на определенной странице только какую-то его часть. Например для страницы product создать класс product и юзать только его и события кот в нем определены, но на странице account все что в product не должно вызываться и не должны срабатывать бинды т.к. для account есть свой класс.
5. Должна быть возможность собирать такой "большой" выходной файл из множества маленьких (юзать всякие include), например чтобы каждый класс (или интерфейс) описать в отдельном файле.
6. По возможности не должно быть много трудности для перехода сайта из того состояния как я описал выше в то которое хочется.

Подскажите, что мне для этого лучше использовать и как решить задачку?

p.s.

Из много найденного, понравился TypeScript, но не уверен до конца в нем. Есть ли там инклуды чтоб по файлам все разбить? Умеет ли он сжимать код при компиляции (минифицировать)? И стоит ли его выбирать?

Comment: Для каких целей будет использоваться препроцессор? Если необходимо только минифицировать и объединить скрипты в один файл то, нужно использовать специально предназначенные для этого средства.

Comment: Нужно минифицировать, объединить, и скажем, добавить возможности TypeScript. TypeScript в одиночку все это не сможет же?

Comment: Все это можно будет сделать, если использовать, например, VS2012 который будет выполняться все необходимые вам задачи.

Comment: а если я ограничен только исп. Idea 14 ?

Comment: Значит нужно читать документацию и искать информацию в интернете. Я с ней не сталкивался и помочь ничем не могу.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript - это транспайлер, надстройка над JavaScript, его цель - если очень грубо - писать более красивый код. К сожалению, именно он вам вряд ли много чем поможет.

То, о чем вы говорите - собрать файлы, минифицировать их - называется сборщиком. В мире javascript существует один известный сборщик - [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), им, насколько мне известно, пользуется большинство js-программистов. Я не могу по нему проконсультировать, т.к. работаю в другом поле, но могу гарантировать, что с этими задачами он справится. насколько знаю, TypeScript он спокойно скомпилирует в js, нужно просто поставить плагин.

По поводу

> В итоге, полученный большой файл, нужно использовать не целиком всегда, а на определенной странице только какую-то его часть. Например для страницы product создать класс product и юзать только его и события кот в нем определены, но на странице account все что в product не должно вызываться и не должны срабатывать бинды т.к. для account есть свой класс.

Тут есть два решения (точнее, три). Первое - js-way - это AMD, Asynchronous Module Definition в связке с [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html). Вы просто в скрипте указываете, что ему нужно, а он сам подтягивает необходимые файлы. Таким образом у вас может загружаться только require.js и файл с самими биндами, а уж через скрипт с биндами подтягиваются файлы-зависимости. Это создает тучу запросов, но это реально js-подход, который обеспечивает приложению единообразность.

Второе решение - это сборка на стороне сервера, которая требует определенных штук от сервера (например, [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic)). На странице просто указывается, какие файлы должны собраться и отдаться, например, Symfony умеет вот так:

```
{% javascripts filter="coffee" filter="uglifyjs2"
    "/app/legacy.js"
    "/app/modern.coffee"
    output="/app/combined.js"
%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Это очень круто и некруто одновременно. Из плюсов:

- Абсолютная гибкость в модулях
- Один запрос от фронтенда к серверу

Из минусов:

- Бэкенд начинает управлять фронтендом
- Фронтенду приходится думать, как ему извращаться в том случае, если в файле не оказалось всего необходимого

Поэтому я бы рекомендовал первый подход.

И, наконец, про третий. Раз уж идет рефакторинг - почему бы не пойти еще дальше, и не воспользоваться реальным фреймворком (например, [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/))? Он сам будет контролировать наличие нужных элементов на странице и реагировать на них, уничтожив проблему с биндами процентов на 90.